# Highlight text inside table on click

Tags: javascript

I got a piece of code here which creates a highlightable textarea on click. I like the way it works. However, I just want to make the textarea look simple. I'm trying to use a table (1 row/3 columns) instead with same functionality.

Is there a way I can use a table that will highlight the text inside it on click? Any expert advice on how I can achieve this?

```
<textarea style="color: black; background-color: lightyellow; border:1px solid #AD8C08" rows="2" cols="35" onclick="this.focus();this.select()" readonly="readonly">Box 1</textarea>
<textarea style="color: black; background-color: lightyellow; border:1px solid #AD8C08" rows="2" cols="35" onclick="this.focus();this.select()" readonly="readonly">Box 2</textarea>
<textarea style="color: black; background-color: lightyellow; border:1px solid #AD8C08" rows="2" cols="35" onclick="this.focus();this.select()" readonly="readonly">Box 3</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the `HTMLTableCellElement.prototype.select`, as follows:

```js
if (!('select' in HTMLTableCellElement)) {
  HTMLTableCellElement.prototype.select = function() {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(this);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="color: black; background-color: lightyellow; border:1px solid #AD8C08" rows="2" cols="35" onclick="this.select()">Box 1</td>
    <td style="color: black; background-color: lightyellow; border:1px solid #AD8C08" rows="2" cols="35" onclick="this.select()">Box 2</td>
    <td style="color: black; background-color: lightyellow; border:1px solid #AD8C08" rows="2" cols="35" onclick="this.select()">Box 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**NOTE**

If you don't want to [change the prototype of a class you don't own](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/), you can create a method, e.g:

```
function selectElement(el) {
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(el);
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);
}
```

And then call it in your `td` elements, e.g:

```
<td onclick="selectElement(this)">Box 1</td>
```